# ln: the symbolic link "/documents" could not be created: The requested function is not implemented

Tags: symbolic-link, webdav

Why I can't create a symbolic link in a webdav folder? In a normal folder is it working.

```
ln -s /home/argonist/Dokumente/ ./Dokumente
```

Comment: webdav? how? ln only works on filesystems that support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (without the trailing slash)

```
ln -s /home/argonist/Dokumente ./Dokumente
```

If doesn't work. Is there any error message shown?

Comment: Symlinks always seem to work for me with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: error message: "the symbolic link “/documents” could not be created: The requested function is not implemented." It is not working. psusi says webdav does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create it because webdav does not support symlinks.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another ways?

Comment: @Argonist, don't use webdav?